# ListView Visible if multiple rows

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, visibility

How do I bind the ListViews visibility to a calculation? I want the Listviews to be visible ONLY if there are more than one record in the DataContexts Collection (IEnumerable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a property **CollectionAny** on a **ViewModel**, which will call **IEnumerable.Any()** method. You can return **Visibility** directly from your **ViewModel**, but it is not recommended by **MVVM** pattern. So you are able to use converter, such as **BooleanToVisibilityConverter**. If you can wrap your collection to a **ICollecitionView** interface, you can use its **IsEmpty** property. If it is your choice - you do not need to  raise **PropertyChanged** event.

Here example of binding boolean property to Visibility:

```
<!-- Inside your resources define the converter instance -->
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2VConverter">
...

<ListView 
    ...
    Visibility="{Binding Path=CollectionAny, Converter={StaticResource B2VConverter}}" 
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the visibility of the list view to the collection through a converter like so

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" 
ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionWithObjectsIn}" 
Visibility="{Binding CollectionWithObjectsIn, Converter={StaticResource      
 CollectionCountToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

In the CollectionCountToVisibilityConverter you have to create, you would then check the count of items in the Collection passed in and then return the correct Visibility value

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `Visibility` to `HasItems`:

```
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myList, Path=HasItems}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```